# How to display all messages in a conversation style in Django?

Tags: django, templates, messaging

I'm trying to make a simple messaging feature for my web app. I have the following views for creating and listing conversations i.e. groups of messages between two users.

**views.py**

```
class CreateMessageView(CreateView):
    model = Message
    fields = ['msg']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.frm = frm = self.request.user
        form.instance.to = to = User.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.thread = "%s & %s" % (frm, to) if int(frm.id) < int(to.id) else "%s & %s" % (to, frm)
        return super(CreateMessageView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateMessageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['to'] = User.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).get_full_name()
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('main:message-list')

class ListMessageView(ListView):
    model = Message

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(Q(to=self.request.user) | Q(frm=self.request.user)).order_by('-created', 'thread')
```

**message_list.html**

```
<h3>Messages</h3>

{% regroup object_list by thread as threads %}

<ul>
{% for item in threads %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'main:thread' item.grouper %}"> {{ item.grouper }} </a></li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No messages to show. Send a message to someone today!</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I am trying to use the `regroup` feature to group messages with the same conversation name. However, this shows the `conversation name` on the list, but I want to show the name of the person on the other end of the conversation. How can I achieve this?